# Why is my WHERE clause not working in SQL?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub BTNupdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNupdate.Click

    con.Open()
    Dim LRN As Integer = TextBoxLRN.Text
    Dim FULLNAME As String = TextBoxFullName.Text
    Dim GENDER As String = ComboBoxGen.SelectedItem
    Dim COURSE As String = TextBoxCourse.Text
    Dim SECTION As String = TextBoxSection.Text

    query = "UPDATE StudentInfoTbl 
             SET [FULL NAME] = @FULLNAME, [GENDER] = @GENDER, [COURSE] = @COURSE, 
             [SECTION] = @SECTION 
             WHERE [LRN] = @LRN ;"  --> 'HERE IS THE ERROR

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LRN", TextBoxLRN.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FULL NAME", TextBoxFullName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GENDER", ComboBoxGen.SelectedItem)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COURSE", TextBoxCourse.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECTION", TextBoxSection.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show(TextBoxLRN.Text & " Record hass been successfully updated!", "Record Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    ClearTextBox()
    BindData()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

my WHERE clause in SQL query is not being read but when I remove the WHERE clause, all the data from my data table are updated. I want to specify that LRN data will be updated.

Comment: If you are using MS-Access then you are using an OleDb provider. This provider doesn't allow the parameters to be out-of-order in respect at how they are used in the string. @LRN should be the last one in the sequence of AddWithValue calls

Comment: sir Steve still nothing happens. I put them orderly. and set the @LRN AddWithValue calls at the last..

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer that is the number of the rows updated. If it is bigger than zero then the query has updated something. It it is zero then the data you are trying to update doesn't exist. There is also the possibility that you are trying to update a different database and not the one you are looking at. What is your connectionstring?

Comment: Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Documents\VB.NET PROJECS\InsertDeleteUpdateSearhVbProgram\Database\InsertDeleteUpdateSearch1.accdb")

Comment: So what value does ExecuteNonQuery return?

Comment: Notice you’ve using parameter.addwithvalue(), then assigning it the string value TextBoxLRN.Text.  Did you realise this will type your param as a string?  Notice further up your code your declaration for LRN as a integer.  Do you have a type mismatch there?

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` before anything else, then turn `Parameters.AddWithValue()` into `Parameters.Add()`, specifying the correct datatype. The parameters, as already mentioned, need to be added in the same order as specified in the SQL: OleDb parameters are positional, not named.